# comma for tomorrow in the middle of sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas

I  am having a problem with punctuation before and after the word 'tomorrow' when it is used in the middle of a sentence. In the
example below, can I use ',' both before and after tomorrow?

> I can assure you that, tomorrow, I will create as much chaos as I can

Answer (score 1):

If you put commas before and after (it not incorrect), you indicate that you *really* want to emphasise that your chaos will occur tomorrow and not today or any other day.

The sentence would be equally correct if you decide to omit the commas

> I can assure you that tomorrow I will create as much chaos as I can.

or to keep the comma only before

> I can assure you that, tomorrow I will create as much chaos as I can.

However, I think that you cannot put a comma only after the word 'tomorrow'. If you want to put a comma after, this obliges you to put one before as well.